# PHPUnit fatal error 'call to undefined function xcache_get()' AWS SDK & Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, phpunit

I'm trying to get PHPUnit up and running in my Symfony 2 app, but I'm running into a problem I can't seem to figure out.

When I run my unit test a Fatal Error is returned, this does not happen inside of a normal browser.

**Test function**

```
    $client = static::createClient(array(), array(
        'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'test',
        'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'test',
    ));        
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/test/url');
```

**Error in console**

```
 $ phpunit -c app/
 PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

 Configuration read from /Acme/app/phpunit.xml.dist

 PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function xcache_get() in /Acme/vendor/aws-sdk-for-php/lib/cachecore/cachexcache.class.php on line 58

 Fatal error: Call to undefined function xcache_get() in /Acme/vendor/aws-sdk-for-php/lib/cachecore/cachexcache.class.php on line 58
```

**Line error refers to (In AWS SDK) L 58 is L 3 in this excerpt**

```
    public function read()
{   
    if ($data = xcache_get($this->id))
    {
        $data = $this->gzip ? gzuncompress($data) : $data;
        return unserialize($data);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Any help much appreciated :-)

Comment: Looks like you don't have XCache extension, or phpunit is using different ini file that does not load this extension.

Comment: I'm using MAMP with Xcache, that URL works perfectly in the browser so I'm assuming your second point may be part of the problem? How would I find out which ini file it is using?

Comment: by running php --ini from console, compare it with `phpinfo()` output from the browser to see what ini files are being loaded (most probably your web server runs on different user and may have it's own ini file)

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help, if you want to post as an answer i'll accept it. The command line was using a different php.ini file to MAMP, as soon as I put the xcache config inside it it started working as expect. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpunit is using different ini file that does not load this extension

Try running php --ini from console, compare it with phpinfo() output from the browser to see what ini files are being loaded (most probably your web server runs on different user and may have it's own ini file)

Possible ways to fix it:

1. Editing ini used by cli and adding necessary options
2. By setting PHPRC enviroment variable to point to MAMP ini file
3. Create symlink to the MAMP ini file in php bin folder
4. Edit phpunit file and add `-c path/to/ini` after php binary

Comment: How can I entirely change the path to ini to the MAMP file? If I copy and paste the entire contents I get a bunch of require_once path errors.  I did initially copy/paste the xcache stuff which fixed one problem but led to another. Ideally this command line config will be the exact same as MAMP

Comment: If I add in var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent()); to find the error I get more xcache problems:  Warning: xcache_get(): xcache.var_size is either 0 or too small to enable var data caching in /Users/greg/Repos/hvh/vendor/aws-sdk-for-php/lib/cachecore/cachexcache.class.php line 58